# To include whole package or just specific jars?

Tags: java, jar, war

My Java project is using some 3rd party jar packages. When I produce final war file, should I include the 3rd party packages as a whole - or should I pick just specific jars from each package, jars that my project uses? What is the rigth way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Obviously, your war file should package all the third party libraries(JAR files) that you use. What do you mean by specific JARs from each package?

Comment: Let's say I use some Tomahawk library which has 20 jars. I see that my app works ok with ony 3 jars (how to make sure this is true in all cases is another question I need to ask). The question is: should I copy only 3 jars to WEB-INF\lib or should I copy all 20? What's the right thing to do?

Comment: Unless you're using a tool like Maven which will resolve your transitive dependencies, it will be mostly trial-and-error to find the ones you really need. In most cases, the names of the jars will give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to package all dependent jars into your WAR file's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Most build tools like Ant or Maven do this by default.

Repackaging on a package-by-package basis is possible if you're conscious about the final size of your WAR file, but is an exception. This is more frequently done if you're dealing with things like client deployments (e.g. WebStart), where you need to keep the download size to a minimum.

Recommendation: Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused with "package all dependent jars". Did you mean that I include the whole package, or to test which jars are "dependent" and actually used by my code?

Comment: Well, you need some way to define which libraries you're using. Let's say you're using some classes from Jakarta Commons Lang (`StringUtils` etc.), then that means that you will have to include the commons-lang jar file. How are you compiling your code, using Eclipse? The libraries you're using there should give an indication on what you need to include. A tool like Maven will also help you with this, since it let's you define dependencies and will also help with bundling them.

Comment: So you are saying not to include the whole package but just jars that are used (and their dependencies)?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. It only signals errors when some jar is missing. Then I usualy add the whole package to project, and this resolves problems.

Comment: If you want to be save, just include them all. A tool like Maven will help you manage this better.

Comment: One way would be to start with no jars at first, then add them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be "it depends...".

In case you run other web applications that make use of the same 3rd parties it would be good idea to place these jars in some shared location (all application servers provide such directory). The classes your web app needs in runtime will be loaded from this shared location and will be available for your webapp. This approach will make your war smaller and reduce the deploy time.

Example: you have webapp1 and webapp2 both using jsf-api.jar - there is no reason to package this jar with both of them - you can throw it into a shared library. In situation you are describing with 3 jars vs 20 jars I would use some tool for analyzing the dependency graph of your application (in order to package as few as possible). Dependency graph tool I worked with: [CDA - Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) is an external tool and it produces dependency graphs much more readable than the [Classycle](http://classycleplugin.graf-tec.ch/index.html) Eclipse plugin or Eclipse class dependencies view.(Probably other IDEs have better tools? I guess that IntelliJ does...)

However, in case different web apps use different versions of the same 3rd party jar you may run into version collisions.
Resolving these collisions might be [PITA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PITA) and you will need to understand how the deploy mechanism of your app server vendor works (class loading policies for both component and application). So, the safest () would be to include the jars you need under the WEB-INF\lib of your war.

Comment: Thanks, but the question isnt't where to put jars, but which jars to put. Let's say I use Tomahawk library which has 20 jars. I see that my app works ok with ony 3 jars (how to make sure this is true in all cases is another question I need to ask). The question is: should I copy only 3 jars to WEB-INF\lib or should I copy all 20? What's the *right* thing to do?

Comment: @Danijel, I tried to say that you should try to package as few 3rd party jars with your app as possible, e.g. you have webapp1 and webapp2 both using jsf-ap1.jar there is no reason to package this jar with both of them - you can throw it into a shared lib. In situation you are describing with 3 jars vs 20 jars I would use some tool for analyzing the dependency graph of your application (in order to package as few as possible). Dependency graph tool I worked with: CDA - Class Dependency Analyzer is an external tool and it produces dependency graphs much more readable than the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Will try to minimize the number of jars I ship. Will try CDA.